# Interpreting a JVM Class cast exception error message - what is the original type that can't be casted

Tags: java, jvm, classcastexception

I have a Java production system with IBM JVM running on Linux.
A customer reports the following exception printed to the log:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: [B incompatible with java.lang.String`
When trying to cast the individual attributes returned from:  `javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext(...)`
From this exception I can't figure out what is the type that could not be converted to String. What is "B"?

Normally, I know that a class cast error message should look something like this:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer incompatible with java.lang.String`
But as you can see it's not the case in the first printout.
I thought that there might be an actual class named B, but I could find one under javax.naming...
Is there a name obfuscation going on here?
I now plan to send the customer a version that will print out the class of the instance before trying to cast to string:
`i.getClass().getCanonicalName()`
But these ping pongs take a week, if you have an idea and could help me out before that, that would be super!

Comment: This behavior isn't specific to the IBM JVM, by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[B` is an array of `byte` (i.e. a `byte[]`). Note that the `[` is a part of the name.

See the [API for `Class.getName()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) for the rules on how those names are produced.